# Creating a sqlite table in terminal (iOS)

Tags: sqlite

```
sqlite> create table t
...>  SELECT *  FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='t';
Error: near "SELECT": syntax error
sqlite>
```

I'm trying to create a table called 't' in terminal. I'm getting the error. Maybe I'm missing somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you need to use here is `CREATE TABLE AS ... SELECT`:

```
> CREATE TABLE t AS SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = 't';
```

Comment: sqlite> CREATE TABLE t AS SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name 't';
Error: near "'t'": syntax error

Comment: I'm still seeing the error.. what I did was... typing sqlite3 and then typing .open myDBName.db before I type your code.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo, use `WHERE ... name = 't'`